# Updating mpl_toolkits mplot3d quivers using AnimationFunc

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, vector, 3d

I would like to update the data in my 3D quivers.

Project outline - I have an ESP32 feeding position data through my USB port and I want to chart it's travel vector in a single quiver, but quickly.

I am using `matplotlib's animation.FuncAnimation()` `blit=True` function to update a 2d line chart with it's roll/pitch/yaw status.

For the line chart I keep a rolling history of the last 200 data values. The code looks like:

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

# The number of values that are going to be charted
log_size = 200

# Create a figure instance and add a line chart
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

# Create static arrays that data will pass through
xs = list(range(0, log_size))
ys_roll = [np.NaN] * log_size

# Set the expected chart limits, 
# x-number of data points and y-data range
ax.set_xlim([0, log_size])
ax.set_ylim([-180, 180])

# Setup the lines that are going to be streamed 
# with names for legend
line0, = ax.plot(xs, ys_roll, label="Roll")

# Establish chart parameters 
plt.title('Roll, Pitch, and Yaw')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Angle')
plt.legend()

X, Y, Z = 0, 0, 0
U, V, W = np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')
ax1.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax1.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax1.set_zlim([-1, 1])

vec0 = ax1.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W)

# Format plot
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)

ser = ... # Serial port setup here

def get_readings(ser):
    # Function to get serial port readings and return an np.array() with 6 elements:
    # Roll, Pitch, Yaw, and vector U, V, W.
    ...
    return np.array([roll_val, pitch_val, yaw_val, U, V, W]) 

def animate(i, ser, ys_roll):
    # Get USB readings from function above
    pos = get_readings(ser)
    
    # Element 0 is Roll
    ys_roll.append(pos[0])
    
    # Limit y lists to log_size
    ys_roll = ys_roll[-log_size:]

    # Update the y items
    line0.set_ydata(ys_roll)
    # Elements 3, 4, and 5 are vector U, V, W
    ax1.quiver(0, 0, 0, pos[3], pos[4], pos[5], length=1)
    
    return line0, ax1

# setup plot to call animate() funciton periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(ser, ys_roll), interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

I know I can use `ax1.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W)` to create a new quiver, and but I have to run `ax1.clear()` in order to clear up the last quiver which also clears my last axis settings.

I would like to use something like the `line0.set_ydata()` function but more like `vec0.set_udata()` so that I can update the data behind the chart rather than rebuilding the whole chart (which is too slow).

I've tried looking at the variables in VisualStudio and I know the quiver is of the Line3DCollection but I can't see/I am not sure of any functions within that allow me to change the data.

Can the masters of mpl_toolkits or matplotlib offer any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Typical after posting the question, I solve the problem 5 minutes later.

There is a function called `set_segments()` that I can call from `vec0`. The problem I was having was trying to return `vec0` after calling the function where I should have returned `ax1`.

The code being

```py
def animate(i, ser, ys_roll):
    ...
    # Update vector segments
    vec0.set_segments([[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [pos[3], pos[4], pos[5]]]])
    
    return ..., ax1
```

What threw me was returning `ax1` rather than returning `vec0` - like in the `line0` case.